# S-function builder not giving output)

Tags: anonymous-function, simulink

I'm totally new to programming and `sfunctions builder (simulink)`.
Pardon me if I'm not providing correct/required/relevant info.

I had compile my C code from `lustre` language for a `PID
controller`. I'm supposed to implement the `PID controller` C code
into `sfunction builder` in `simulink`. I compile the `sfunction`
builder and it compiles successfully but its not giving an output at
all.

What is going wrong? What more information can I provide to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Show us the code you've placed in Outputs and Derivatives tabs in the S-function Builder block.